# Migrating project from VS 2012 to VS 2015

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I am currently working on MVC4 in `.net`. But I want to migrate it to MVC6.

Can you please tell me  what are the necessary steps I need to do  to migrate it from visual studio 2012 to visual studio 2015.

Comment: Suggestion: update to MVC5 in VS2013 and ensure everything works. Then update to VS2015 again ensuring everything works. Only then think about the big changes in MVC6.

Comment: How about directly compiling the project in  VS2015. I think MS  .net 4.6 should support earlier also.

Comment: MVC6 uses .Net Core (the new, lightweight, cloud optimised version); to use .NET 4.6 (the full version) you need to target MVC5.

Comment: You can only recreate the project and copy useful code. No migration tools yet to automate that.